# jQuery $.each function not returning any results

Tags: jquery, json, each

I have a `json` response as below :

```
[
    {
        "Sublocation":
        {
            "id":"1",
            "name":"Beltola",
            "location_id":"1"
        }
    },
    {
        "Sublocation":
        {
            "id":"2",
            "name":"Ganeshguri",
            "location_id":"1"
        }
    },
    {
        "Sublocation":
            {
                "id":"3",
                "name":"Kahilipara",
                "location_id":"1"
            }
    }
]
```

I am trying to alert the names of sublocations :

```
function render_ui(resp)
  {
    $.each(resp,function(index,obj){
      alert(obj.Sublocation.name);
    }

  }
```

But the function is not alerting anything ! Whats the reason ?

Comment: Any errors in the console..? Did you parse that as a JSON..?

Comment: @Nitish: Given that there's a syntax error, that's very doubtful.

Answer (score 5):

You have a syntax error, you are not closing the call to `$.each`

```
function render_ui(resp) {
  $.each(resp,function(index, obj) {
    alert(obj.Sublocation.name);
  });
}
```

Comment: OMG ! thanks a lot. and sorry for posting this :( I should have check these errors !

Answer (score 0):

```
function render_ui(resp) {
  $.each(resp,function(i, val) {
    console.log(val.Sublocation.name);
  });
}
```

[**WORKING jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LpFV8/)